# Regex c# should not match Boolean Operators

Tags: c#, regex, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to write a regular expression which should be able to identify boolean expressions.

I need to avoid cases like `IF(AND AND AND)`.  That is, the name of the variable shouldn't be one of the following operators `(OR;AND;XOR)`.

I also tried to use `[^(OR)]` but this wasn't helpful. My Regex looks like this:

```
(?:<Name> [A-Za-z0-9])
```

Is there any chance to write a Regex which could find a string like OR and then don't match it?

**Update:**

@Kobi - I tried your solution and it works fine. Is there any other ways to do stuff like this may one for dummies. I want to write readable code

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a negative lookahead:

```
(?<Name>\b(?!(?:and|x?or)\b)[A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

This assumes you're trying to match a single literal, like "IF(**this** AND **this**)". The regex checks before taking letters, if all it sees is "and" "or" or "xor", it fails.

Also, make sure you have the right `RegexOptions` set - you probably want `IgnoreCase` on, and unless you have `IgnorePatternWhitespace` the space in your original pattern might fail a match, there is no space in `if(var1`, for example.

Comment: @user359446 - I'm not sure what that means `:|`

Comment: I will try your solution thx 
The regex shouldn´t match if there is any of the boolean expressions

Comment: It needs to be `(?<name>..)`, not `(?:<name>...)`. That was already wrong in @user359446's question.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks, fixed. I tested the regex, but not in .Net, so I omitted that part. Thanks.